# data cleaning from strings stored in lists in python

Tags: python, string

I have some test data scraped and struggle in how to clean it correctly in terms of efficiency.

```
test_data = ['\r\n    \r\n        ',
                  '\r\n          ',
                  'Reine Baumwolle',
                  '\r\n        ',
                  '\r\n      \r\n        ',
                  '\r\n          ',
                  'Kontrastblende am Ausschnitt',
                  '\r\n        ',
                  '\r\n      \r\n        ',
                  '\r\n          ',
                  'Pflegeleicht',
                  '\r\n        ',
                  '\r\n      \r\n    ']
```

**Via regular expression** I can clean my data so far:

```
import re
rep = ['\n','\t','\r']
for y in rep:
test_data = [r.replace(y, '') for r in test_data]
```

**My interim result** is like this:

```
['            ', 
'          ',
'Reine Baumwolle',
'        ',
'              ',
'          ',
'Kontrastblende am Ausschnitt',
'        ',
'              ',
'          ',
'Pflegeleicht',
'        ',
'          ']
```

How could I extend my function to clean all of the unnecessary with-spaces and commas to get only one string as the following:

**expected result:**

```
test_data = 'Reine Baumwolle, Kontrastblende am Ausschnitt, Pflegeleicht'
```

**OR** just without comma-seperation:

```
test_data = 'Reine Baumwolle Kontrastblende am Ausschnitt Pflegeleicht'
```

Comment: Your `test_data` is not a valid Python list, can you fix it?

Comment: @timgeb sorry, is done so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `list comprehension.`

**Ex:**

```
test_data = ['\r\n    \r\n        ', '\r\n          ', 'Reine Baumwolle', '\r\n        ','\r\n      \r\n        ','\r\n          ','Kontrastblende am Ausschnitt','\r\n        ','\r\n      \r\n        ','\r\n          ','Pflegeleicht','\r\n        ','\r\n      \r\n    ']
print( " ".join([i for i in test_data if i.strip()]) )
print( ", ".join([i for i in test_data if i.strip()]) )  #Comma Seperated.
```

**Output:**

```
Reine Baumwolle Kontrastblende am Ausschnitt Pflegeleicht
Reine Baumwolle, Kontrastblende am Ausschnitt, Pflegeleicht
```

- `str.strip` to remove any leading or trailing space.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to filter out strings for which there would not be anything left after stripping them from whitespace.

```
>>> ' '.join(s for s in test_data if s.strip())
'Reine Baumwolle Kontrastblende am Ausschnitt Pflegeleicht'
```